# Calculating length of polyline defined by list of coordinates using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, line, distance, length

I have a list of coordinates, knowing that I am working using EPSG:4326 and using Python I would like to calculate the length in kilometres of the polyline defined by these coordinates.

```
Coords = [(0.0, 50.787944),
 (0.0, 50.787944),
 (-0.20159865271498856, 50.824569950535725),
 (-0.40044683717220364, 50.803694),
 (-0.599761967889834, 50.78975316549538)]
```

I've tried with GeoPandas and shapely but reading the documentation I can't find an easy way to do it. Is there any function that allows me to calculate the length in kilometre knowing Coords and the reference system used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545704/fast-haversine-approximation-python-pandas

Comment: @Taras trying to post the code that I wrote I end up finding the solution, I am not sure it is right but I've posted it as an answer. Thanks for your encouragement.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I have understood the steps to follow I had to convert the EPSG:4326 which has degrees as for units to a coordinate system in meters as EPSG:32618. So eventually I have end up following the instructions in the shapely documentation for [transformations](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#other-transformations).

```
Coords = [(0.0, 50.787944),
 (0.0, 50.787944),
 (-0.20159865271498856, 50.824569950535725),
 (-0.40044683717220364, 50.803694),
 (-0.599761967889834, 50.78975316549538)] 
 
polyline = LineString(Coords)
```

After converting the list of coordinates to a shapely `LineString` I used `pyproj` for computing the transformation. I had initially a `attributeError : module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'CRS'` because I was using an old version.

```
import pyproj

from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform


wgs84 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:4326')
utm = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:32618')
utm_polyline = transform(project, wgs84_pt)
length_km = utm_polyline.length/1000
```

If using pyproj < 2.1:

```
from functools import partial
import pyproj

from shapely.ops import transform


wgs84 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
utm = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32618')

project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    wgs84,
    utm)

utm_polyline = transform(project, polyline)
length_km = utm_polyline.length/1000
```

Comment: You used the wrong UTM zone.  UTM zone 18N is documented for "Between 78°W and 72°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Bahamas. Canada - Nunavut; Ontario; Quebec. Colombia. Cuba. Ecuador. Greenland. Haiti. Jamica. Panama. Turks and Caicos Islands. United States (USA). Venezuela." I wouldn't use UTM for the UK, since it straddles zones 29&30.

Comment: @Vince thanks a lot, I did this for an experiment in my thesis in surface metrology so I am not very familiar with CRS should I use EPSG:27700? Please post an answer if you know a better way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Vince I was really impressed that you understood it was UK. Very good observation :-)

Comment: As a rule, you should probably use the projection the national mapping agency uses. 50E,0N is in the Indian Ocean, so it wasn't hard to figure you were at 50N,0E